# How to control App over lockscreen in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Like the titel saying, I want to control my „flutter“ app when I lock the screen (maybe also Show some part, like one widget).
Like google-maps, when you Kick the screen when navigation is running. Or controling music when I lock the screen. (Or maybe control over the earphones)

I searched the whole google results (to page 2-3).
All I can find is, how include an individual lock screen in my app.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this: https://pub.dev/packages/awesome_notifications
because you can not do it by yourself, the only way is using notifications...

Comment: Hello Andre. Ty for yor answer. This is not what I am looking for. I don't want to reply or something. I want something like "music fatforward" for other things like "To-Do-List". Unfortunately it is not possible. I researched a lot. And the only possible way would be, to do it over the music Buttons. But then I would also cut the Music funktions when I am hearing Spotify...